# Up button should bring previous passed commands

Tags: c

so I am designing an application, where similar to bash, when the user presses the up and down keys, the previously passed input(or commands) should be printed. I know Java has key listeners, but I have no clue how to do this in C.

Comment: Have you looked into [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)?

Comment: @crynix please read before you post. I just said I have no clue how to use key listeners in C, or if such a thing exists. I obviously Googled to find such a thing and failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`GNU readline`](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html). It's actually what Bash uses.

Comment: can I write a key listener, if yes, what is the library and where is an example?

Comment: I just want to know how to print hello world when a use presses the up button

Comment: The `up` key reaches your application in the same way anything the user types does: through `stdin`. This is the baseline. Implementing something akin to a Java listener on top of that is not trivial. If you want a higher-level interface that won't do the work for you (as does `readline`), try `ncurses`.

Comment: I was thinking of using getchar but that requires the user to press the enter button after the up button is pressed

Comment: Exactly what `ncurses` solves for you. Can you please google what I'm recommending? :D

Comment: Okay one last question, why is the up and down key both 27? For example, int main()
{
    int c = getchar();
 
    printf("the char was %d", c);
}  This code returns 27 for both up and down, how can I distinguish sir?

Comment: please help, I don't know why up and down are both 27

Comment: Special function keys send escape sequences, 27 is the ESC character that begins the sequence. Up sends `ESC [ A`, down sends `ESC [ B`, and so on. Libraries like ncurses provide functions that recognize escape sequences and translate them into key codes.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. Please, Richard, google up a nice `ncurses` tutorial. You won't regret it :). You may also consider accepting the answer to your question.